# cannot fix: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have read many of the related posts about this but cannot figure out how to fix the following.

Here is a link to a zip of this super simple example.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auri_uzbtK_to4AGo1yammz7PRrv6w?e=QOtQeL

I am using VS Code.  I have the following python program structure shown below.

I am trying to run and debug "run_tests.py".  When I do, VS Code throws the error "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

The line in question is in file helper.py
"from ...inpatient.model import Model"

I am stuck on how to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
MyApp/
    inpatient/
        __init__.py
        model.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        run_tests.py
        utils/
            __init__.py
            helper.py
    venv
```

run_tests.py

```
import unittest
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
from utills.helper import some_method

class BaseFludlTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

helper.py

```
from ...inpatient.model import Model

def some_method():
    model = Model()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, my misunderstanding was that "import" in python were relatively to where the main program was executed.

with this new knowledge, I moved my running code to the root and now things operate as a expect.